# Reverse-proxied nginx exposing port number when redirecting directory index requests

Tags: nginx

I have nginx backend that's used to serve static files. Nginx is running on a non-standard port (e.g. 8080). It is publicly accessible via a reverse proxy on port 80.

The setup works fine for the most part. However, if a request is made to a directory, nginx returns a 301 redirect with the port set to 8080.

All the questions I could find were about nginx being a reverse proxy rather than the actual server. Any help would be very much appreciated!

As an illestration of this problem, the URL `http://example.com/dir/` works fine. But leaving the trailing slash `http://example.com/dir` causes the browser to redirect to `http://example.com:8080/dir`.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/port_in_redirect

Comment: Hi Alexey Ten, I've tried adding this to the configuration file, but it doesn't seem to have had any affect. (ofc, after restarting the server)

Comment: So show your configuration

Comment: sorry for the late response. I've added the nginx configuration for that server.

Comment: I think I found the root of the problem: chrome. Chrome seems to be aggressively caching 301 redirects and not clearing them with Ctrl-R or F5. Your proposed solution seems to have done the trick. Thank you! (PS: you should add the the directive as the solution to this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`port_in_redirect`](http://nginx.org/r/port_in_redirect) directive for this. You should turn it off.

```
server {
    ...
    port_in_redirect off;
    ...
}
```

Also, it's better to test redirects (especially permanent redirects) with console tools like `curl` or `wget`, because your browser is likely already cached redirect and will just use it without actual hit to the server (that's the main reason of permanent redirect).